# Android app is published, but not visible anywhere in Google Play

Tags: android, publishing

I have tested this app on the Android emulators, phones, tablets, and Google TV.  Its works.  When I published it Google Play, the app is not visible.  Below is the manifest. I sincerely appreciate any insight as to the problem.   Thank- you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zzzz.xyzxyz"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.4" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AlbumSelectorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xyzxyzAppWidgetActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectableImagesActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectedImageActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReplayAlbumActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PreferenceHelpActivity" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" >
            </category>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PreferenceSettingsActivity" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" >
            </category>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ReplayAlbumService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zzzz.xyzxyz.ReplayAlbumService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".xyzxyzAppWidgetConfigureActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/appwidget_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".xyzxyzAppWidgetProvider"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/appwidget_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: How long have you waited? It can take a little while for the site and the apps to update their listings.

Comment: How long have you had the application published? It takes some time for it to propagate through and be visible in the markets.

Comment: Also, the fact your hiding your package name means we cant search ourselves to find it :)

Comment: I have been trying for 3 days.  The last time it was uploaded was 15 hours ago.

Comment: Does your app have any spaces in its name? My app does, and if I put the name in quotes, search finds it 2nd on the list, but otherwise doesn't find it at all. Why doesn't the play store algorithm first search for the search term as though quoted? You tell me. It's bananas.

Answer (score 77):

Just try it on your browser setting the link:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename
```

even if it's not indexed in the search, if it's published you will find it, if not, somethings wrong then

Comment: It is visible using the url and it shows to be compatible with my devices.  You have help me tremendously. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!  My company name is incorrect, so my searches failed because of that.  Sincerely appreciate this!!!

Comment: I have the same problem. My app can be found via search or via direct link in Google Play, but is not found in the category top-540 (but should be)

Answer (score 41):

I ran into this problem (or a similar one). I submitted my app on the internal test track and soon after, in the Google play Console, it said my app is Published and provided a link to go to Google Play Store to download the app. However, when I clicked the link, it would tell me the requested URL could not be found. I also could not find the app in the Google Play Store by searching for it.

#### The solution:

Apparently, I had to add myself to the testers group and more importantly - opt in. I found the opt-in link in Google play Console:

1. On the left, click "Release Management"
2. "App releases"
3. Go to the version you have uploaded and click "MANAGE".
4. Click on "Manage testers". There, you will find an opt-in URL.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: "manage testes" in step 4? :) Anyway, had exact same problem as you. This worked.

Comment: You saved the day :-)

Answer (score 23):

Try searching with exact name in double quotes ""

like for eg: `"ZipDrive"`

Comment: Thanks, this works. How to make the app appear without quotes

Comment: Yes, It'w working. But how to How to make the app appear without quotes ?

Comment: @VarunS, It takes some time to fully rollout to all users. Automatically after 1 or 2 days it will starts showing to everyone.

Comment: @Mighty try after few days it will come in search

Answer (score 5):

it might take some time to index it. Until that you might not find it in the search. It is also posible that you don't see it because it doesn't match the device you use to search for it. Or the country you're in.

Comment: how much time it takes in indexing.?? Because i uploaded my app few days back but still it is not showing when i search it through its name.

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj how long did you have to wait? I am having the same problem right now

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj It might happen that the title of the app is a common word that other apps target for. Have you tried finding your developer name + app name?

Comment: agreed, it does take 2-3 days of time to get the published app shown to playstore

Answer (score 4):

I had been waiting ~11 hours and still it wasn't online... until I realised I'd published it but it was still in Beta. I never used the Google Play Alpha/Beta testing features but I still had to click on the button under the Beta tab to "Move to Production".

Answer (score 4):

Here is my first hand experience. I published my first app on the Google play store (GPS) on October 15th. Was pretty excited to locate on GPS. But yes the same experience, it didn't show up.

Then here is the series of events:
**1. Day 1 to Day 3**
When searched using double quotes "Cool Tic Tac Toe", I could see at the bottom of the search list - at the last almost after 200 items, but yes it was there which made me happy.

**2. Day 4 onwards -**
I removed the quotes and searched by app name with the spaces i.e. Cool Tic Tac Toe, it showed up almost at the bottom.
In the mobile or tablet version of Play Store app, you will see filters like **"New" "4.5" or "4.0" for ratings**. So when I used the filters **New** and **4.5** in the play store app, it started showing up almost in the first few pages.

**3. Day 6-7**
My app now shows up at the top (in top 10) when I put the exact app name without any quotes and without using any filters - this is very good sign. So far I have about 100 downloads (most from my friends and family and not from any real user I would imagine as no one in the world will really search my app with its full name.

I realize visitors of GPS would not know my app name, they will search with a generic key word like **Tic Tac Toe** and not **Cool Tic Tac Toe**

**Day 7 onwards - today(8th day)**
I search my app with generic name **Tic Tac Toe** in GPS, it doesn't show up ANYWHERE, not even at the bottom. This is a little disappointing, but I do hope it will crawl up and start showing somewhere.
**HOWEVER** If I add the filters **"New"** and  **"4.5"** it does show up in top 25. This I think is a good sign. I will update more on this if I see any related behavior.

Hope this helps give some idea to my fellow developers who have put their first app in GPS and trying to locate it in the ocean of many millions of other apps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above solutions but I just realised someone can do this below-mentioned mistake too.

- In Play Console, go to Setup-> Advanced settings in the left pane.
- Select Managed Google Play
- Choose the Turn off option, if you want your app to be publicly available.
  [image: Attached image is set for internal organization access only]

Comment: I didn't notice this was this issue but we have already published the app to production and there's no option to turn off anymore. The documentation suggests to create new app with new bundle id but we need to use the same bundle id.. No idea how to maintain the id while making it publicly available

Answer (score 0):

Since you've waited a sufficient amount of time and it should appear, you can try checking your APK to see what default permissions and features your app requires using aapt:

```
$ aapt d badging your.apk
```

Make sure that what is listed for features is not filtering your device.  You can mostly do this on Google Play too, but I have seen a few differences where Google Play will show that it is available for older devices, but it actually will not install.

Also, as suggested by @ricvieira, you should do a query in a web browser to see if your app shows up at all.