# I published an app to the google play store, How do I know which apk was uploaded?

Tags: android, google-play

As title states. I clicked on "Publish" in the google play developer console. And it said my app now got uploaded. But I dont know which apk file was uploaded. How can I find out?

EDIT: I am 100% signed in correctly. Here is an image of the tabs on the left.

[image]

In the tab with the android robot picture, it says I have no applications. But in the tab with the google controller thing, I can click on my app, look at the game details, leaderboards, achievements etc and I can click publish but I dont know what it's publishing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your [Developer Console (All Applications)](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#AppListPlace) and then click on the app. On the left, there is a list of things to choose (Statistics, etc.) so click on APK.

That will tell you everything about the version and version code of the APK. You can click on the latest version to get some details on it, and at the top of the page it even tells you the package name.

Comment: The app doesnt appear there, it says you have no applications

Comment: @Clay: Are you signed on to the correct Google account? Are you sure you uploaded an APK? Send us a screenshot.

Comment: @Clay: So it's a game? I've never used that part of the Dev Console.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Hopefully I can figure it out. I successfully published it before, I have no idea what it published. This is frustrating

Comment: @Clay: It's got to be somewhere. Did you try searching for it on the marketplace? You can go to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=yourDevName` to check all your uploads.

Comment: There's nothing there. I think because I unpublished it

Answer (score 1):

You can by checking the version of the app. Click on all apps -> apk, then you see a list of apk's you uploaded and the current version number.

Comment: It says I dont have any applications. My project is in the tab below the "All Apllications" tab

Comment: When you go to this url, you don't see your app? https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

Comment: I do see it. But I dont see anything under "All Applications"

Comment: You need to click your application and then a second menu is shown on the left side. There you can click on APK.

Comment: All I see on the left hand tab is Game Details, Linked Apps, Achievements, Leaderboards, Testing and Publishing. (Thanks for the help btw)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that after I published it, I quickly unpublished it because I have no idea what it "published"...

Comment: Then i think you need to resend your app. If nothing is shown you don't have any apps uploaded yet.

Comment: I think you need to submit it again to the Google Play store, then it should appear under your applications.

Comment: I created a new Application and just published that. And then I published the game services one too. I wonder if two apps will show lol

Comment: I don't think so. I takes about 1-2 hours before your app is visible in the store. Let us know if submitting a new app has worked for you :)

Comment: Well I saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play and followed the first answer and I cant find anything, so I think something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your app is on play store and not only in play game?
If you upload it with your account should be appared in the tab with android's icon