# Published my App, can find it using my desktop browser, but not through the Android device

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my App on the google play store. I waited the next day and try to find it by using the PlayStore App on my android device. But it did not show up, so I tried my second android device and the same problem can not search for it on the App Store using the PlayStore App.

However, if I search for it using a browser on my desktop I can find it straight away. The App is called Busby Flashlight.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssd.candlelight
```

I am new to publishing so I don't know everything. But I would like to know why I can search for it and find it in a desktop browser but not on my Android device using the PlayStore App?

I have these permission in my manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

And the App minimum SDK is `Gingerbread 2.3.3`

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: possible related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your device filtering on the play store. I went to the google play link and it shows your app incompatible with all of my devices.

Comment: Yes, I have just checked. However, it saids there are no devices supported. And I can't seem to enable all devices. Is there something wrong with my permissions?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to see the compatible devices settings or check if you meet the OS version requirements. If your device does not meet these requirements, the app will not be visible in Google Play on that device.

Comment: Hi, The app will run on devices 2.3.3 up. My devices are 4.4.2 and 4.2.2. I am thinking I have done something wrong with my permissions.

Comment: you could also check country and zone settings, as these also affect what apps are available on google play

Comment: I have listed every country 139 of them.

Comment: did you contact support with your query?