# Android app doesn't shown in google play store

Tags: java, android, publishing

I have created an app and published in play store.. The application can only view above android OS 5.0. But, my minimum sdkversion is 11.. Why i can't see my app in play store list below 5.0.. And how to show app below 5.0...

The following code is my build.gradle code..

```
android 
{
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testing"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChildList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddChild"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".GalleryUtil"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AssignChores"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddReward"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChildDashBoard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Schedule"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPassword"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

`

Comment: The application can only view above android OS 5.0 - do you mean app uses feature available from lollipop? What do you mean by ONLY view?

Comment: Share your manifest file as well

Comment: Minimum SDK version is 11.. But i can't see my application on play store list, with kitkat OS(4.4.4)..

Comment: Try with this URL, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename How long have you had the app published?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play?rq=1

Comment: 4 days ago... i can see the application in above android os 5.0 and also in web..

Comment: There is no need for support-screen tag. Remove them from the Manifest. Secondly, required <uses-feature> for camera and auto-focus. If they are not mandatory, add another tag android:required="false" with-in <uses-feature>

Comment: For more information on the same: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: I second @Yashir here. please remove the support screen tag and uses-feature.

Comment: Thank you... I will try.. If any other suggestion, let me know...

Comment: Is there any issue will occur because of the compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion ?

Comment: No. These are compile related stuff. No impact on Google Play store!