# Not able to find uploaded app on searching with name or package name

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, google-play

I uploaded my APK on play store about 4 days ago, I have more than 40 downloads by sharing the APK link, but still, when I search for APK on play store by name or package name it will never come up.

I am worried that it is happening because I have used some capital letters in the package name, Does anyone knows why it's happening?  Please suggest

Its only showing up by specific link given by play store, also sometime it shows up when I search it on https://play.google.com/store

But when I search it on play Store app it never comes up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app is published, but not visible anywhere in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new app coming up on Google Play Store search takes time and it depends on the following

A. Competitiveness of Title:
If other apps rank for your title, especially if it's a generic term, it may take additional time to index for this search. If you are using a generic term, you may want to prompt users to find your app by searching title + developer name, or rework your title to incorporate a unique word and prompt potential users to search as such.

B. Installs & Retention:
More installs may help speed up indexation (including indexing for your own title), so running a few paid campaigns around launch. Having good user retention for queries (again including your own title) will help to maintain those rankings.

C. Relevance:
You may want to include your title in additional areas to build stronger relevance overall. A few additional areas to consider: App ID, Short Description, and Long Description.