# Android app status is "Production" but can't find it via provided link

Tags: android, google-play-console, publishing, google-play-internal-testing

I submitted my android app on the internal test track and soon after, in the Google Play Console I pushed it under review for production, it said my app is Published and provided a link to go to Google Play Store to download the app. However, when I clicked the link, it would tell me the requested URL could not be found [ScreenShot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHRE.png)

Somebody can please guide me on what possibly I'm doing wrong here? All testing tracks are disabled and interestingly when I make changes into store listing and save it then it still keeps showing production and doesn't show "in review"

I found this answer but it didn't help my case

[Android app is published, but not visible anywhere in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910156/android-app-is-published-but-not-visible-anywhere-in-google-play)

I also tried to connect google support they told me its end users support so I must contact them when I filled their form then they didn't have a chat option and with the calling option it was giving some errors and the only option I was left with the email option so instead of that I'm putting up my questions here that I might find some here or from google who can assist.

Comment: When did you upload this? It can take time for the URLs to update. So you might need to wait overnight

Comment: Yeap, agree but its status is active under production that's causing all this confusion.

Comment: did you guys find a solution ? it's been over 5 days and neither the link nor the search show my app